# Links in TextView

Tags: android, textview, hyperlink

I need to put a link in a `TextView`, I have a string that contains the tag `<a href="link">Text for link</a>` and some other text.
The problem is that if I run the project I can see the text but it's not clickable. I tried with the `<b>` tag too to see if that works and it seems that it doesn't work too.

How can I make this to work without the [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) usage?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Also, why do you not want to use linkify?

Comment: you have to tell your app what to do when you click on the textview (on click event ->open the link

Comment: No, I don't want to make it with linkify

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Thank you for your help all.

I have managed to make this work, after I have found some examples in the android samples.

here is the code:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
            "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
            "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
            "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Hope this help others...

Comment: This solution ignores any phone number and email address links. I'm yet to find a solution which handles all kinds of links (web, phone, email, ...) in the same `TextView`.

Comment: I have a Text View with json response data.that Response contains description and mail id and phone number how can i give click event for mail id and mobile number in that text view android.

Comment: I've done this but how do I know the user clicked it for tracking purposes?

Comment: Note: this will **not** work if you've set in your TextView's properties to autoLink some properties! If you have, you must call `textView.setAutoLinkMask(0);` before you call setText()

Answer (score 47):

Getting links working from html is kind of tricky:

1. Apply your text via xml `android:text="@string/…` or via `setText()` (see other answers)
2. Use `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` to make links clickable (see other answers)
3. Do **NOT** add `android:autoLink="web"` to you XML resource (section `TextView`), otherwise A-tags are not rendered correctly and are not clickable any longer.

Remark 1:
The `OnClickListener` can be helpful, if your `TextView` contains only one link and you want to trigger the navigation even if the user clicks aside your link, but inside the `TextView`.

Remark 2:
`android:linksClickable="true"` still does not work (as of Android 3.2), use p. 2 instead

Comment: It doesn't work if add link string from resource in TextView xml. It's only works with `setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.STRING_NAME)))` for me

Answer (score 32):

Linkify is the class you must use to create links. BTW, what is the reason for not using Linkify?

You can linkify all text in your textview for actions like visiting a website or calling a phone number based on the schema. Android provides the easiest way to do it. Consider the below code.

```
TextView noteView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteview);
noteView.setText(someContent);
Linkify.addLinks(noteView, Linkify.ALL);
```

For creating custom links, the same Linkify class provides various options. 
Google has published [a blogpost on this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) .

Comment: Thanks for help , can you guide me how can i remove underline ?

Comment: This doesn't work for links like `<a href="http://blah.com">http://blah.com</a>`.

Answer (score 26):

I couldn't figure it out, but finally it started working when I did something like:

```
tvTermsOfUse.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.tv_terms_of_use_html)));
Linkify.addLinks(tvTermsOfUse, Linkify.ALL);
tvTermsOfUse.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Text view looks like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_terms_of_use"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

and string res:

```
<string name="tv_terms_of_use_html">
    <![CDATA[This is link to <a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>.]]>
</string>
```

**Important part:**
The `Linkify.addLinks` has to be done **before** `tvTermsOfUse.setMovementMethod`, otherwise it won't work.

No other settings are necessary in XML.

It took me around hour to figure it out myself, hope it helps someone.

**EDIT:**

According to @rfellons comment

> Thanks. Also for me works ... BUT only with
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> ```
>
> on Manifest.xml. –
>   rfellons Sep 7 at 13:31

Make sure you check it as well.

Comment: Absoluty Right! Thanks for the time to write it down!

PEOPLE! THE ANSWER IS HERE!!!!

Comment: Useful answer, help me a lot, thnks!

Comment: Thanks! I tried all other answers in this and other similar questions and none worked. It also didn't work without the CDATA.

Comment: Thanks. Also for me works ... BUT only with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> on Manifest.xml.

Answer (score 20):

Use

```
android:linksClickable="true"
android:autoLink="web"
```

Comment: this is the easiest method out there and it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

I can't reply to your answer for some reason; I just wanted to say that you can omit the `textView.setText` and just put it in a string resource, and set that using `android:text`. You just need to keep the `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`; unfortunately `android:linksClickable="true"` by itself does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution : `Linkify.addLinks(chatText,Linkify.ALL);`

Answer (score 1):

To add the links dynamically (fetched from the server), this works:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                "<a href=" + response.getLink()
                        + ">" + context.getString(R.string.link_from_server) + "</a> "));
```

and in XML add this:

```
android:linksClickable="true"
```

If your strings.xml has this:

```
<string name="link_from_server">Dynamic Link</string>
```

This will add "Dynamic Link" to your text view and if you touch on this, it will go the link provided by your server.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty correcty:(In textview properties,inside xml file)

```
android:autolink="web"
```