# android textview click on a link

Tags: android, hyperlink, click, textview

If I have a textview with spanned text obtained from Html.fromHtml(source), how to make the textview to react when I click on a link? In my textview, link is something like "click here" and this text is a link, it's not a direct link like www.google.com.

Comment: it seems that this is an android os bug. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2219

Comment: [Click this one, it's good for you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790746/links-in-textview/13765953#13765953

Answer (score 6):

```
 android:autoLink="web"
```

Comment: Yes it works. Put that on your TextView, and android:linksClickable="true"

Answer (score 0):

Butter to use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)
Refer [Android Text Links Using Linkify](http://www.indelible.org/ink/android-linkify/)

Comment: but my source code contains html tags... So, to use linkify, I need to get rid manually of these tags and linkify manually all ex link tags... isn't there a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to handle span click event by yourself.
There two ways for this:
1)Create new class extends URLSpan
2)Create new class extends LinkMovementMethod

Please see below url, may be help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16182500/596555

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to your tetView**

```
android:text="@string/Documentation
```

**Add this line to string.xml [ res/values]**

```
<string name="Documentation"><a   href="https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle">Android Activity Lifecycle Documentation</a> 
</string>
```

**Add This code to your MainActivity.java**

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);      textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```