# Android textview link click

Tags: android, click, textview, hyperlink

If I have a textview containing some text and at an certain index is a link (linkified spannablestring). Is there a way to catch the tap or click event over the link (even if the link does not contain an URL)?

Comment: try this one, it's good for you
[click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790746/links-in-textview/13765953#13765953