# Textview link click in fragment - nothing happen

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, android-fragments, layout-inflater

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

I've a FragmentActivity with three fragments. I've a separate class for each fragment in which i build the fragments view.

In this process I create several clickable textview with a weblink. It seems everything is correct and the textviews appears clickable. But nothing happens when I click on a textview.

**Why does nothing happen onTextViewClick?** I would expect to see a list of browser where the link could be opened.

I found a lot of similar questions but couldn't find a mistake in my code so far. Similar questions:

- [How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)
- [handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app)
- [android textview click on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389188/android-textview-click-on-a-link)
- [android textview link click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564331/android-textview-link-click)
- http://jtomlinson.blogspot.ch/2010/03/textview-and-html.html
- http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/

Here is my code of the LinksFragment. A instance of the class is created on the FragmentActivity itself to display this fragment:

```
public class LinksFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return generateView(inflater, container); 
    }

    private View generateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){

        // inflate layout
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_links, container, false);

        // find controls
        LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_links_list);

        // generate list
        String[] links = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.links);
        for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            list.addView(generateClickableTextView(links[i]));
        }

        return view;
    }

    private TextView generateClickableTextView(String text){
        TextView clickableTextView = new TextView(getActivity());       
        clickableTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        clickableTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
        return clickableTextView;
    }
}
```

And the links Array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="links">
        <item><a href="http://www.google.com">- Google</a></item>
        <item><a href="http://www.bing.com">- Bing</a></item>
        <item><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">- Yahoo</a></item>
        <item><a href="http://www.youtube.com">- Youtube</a></item>
        <item><a href="http://www.Vimeo.com">- Vimeo</a></item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**EDIT Solution:**

The solution to my problem was in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125089/1306012

I just had to replace all "<" with "&lt ;" (without the space)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/634474/dymmeh to direct me to this post.

Comment: Check out this answer in regard to putting links in a resource file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10125089/634474