# Adding link to a content parsed from xml file

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am creating a news app.I have succesfully parsed (using sax) the file and added the title in the list view. I want to add link to the title respectively. So once the title is clicked it opens the detailed news of the respective title

How do i add the link to the title.?

this is the [xml file](http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/wales/rss.xml) i use..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Links in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790746/links-in-textview)