# String as a link in TextView

Tags: android, string, android-layout, hyperlink, textview

```
public String getVisualFormInUI(){
    return "Name         :  "+ name +
    "\nRating        :  " + rating +  
    "\nPhone number : " + phoneNumber + 
    "\nAddress      : " + address + 
    "\nMobile Url   : " + mobileUrl ;
}
```

It is the string value of a textview in my activity. Is it possible to represent just mobile url as a link and the others not? And also without creating an other TextView object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let Android render your String as HTML content, like this:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourString));
```

then you can show the mobileUrl as link if you wrap a hyperlink reference around it:

```
<a href='"+ mobileUrl +"'>"+ mobileUrl +"</a>
```

Comment: The second one is correct. In Java, all strings must be surrounded by double quotes (")

Comment: preciesly! i was writing that piece in my program and the second one is working as you say! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Ik have deleted the other incorrect one in your answer but it doesn't appear. May be it will be better if you correct it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [Links in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790746/links-in-textview)

Or:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
        "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
        "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
        "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for more info about problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a URL to be a link, you can simply use the [android:autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) attribute of your `<TextView>` in your XML layout file. If you want to use a more descriptive message as the link, you can use a anchor tag and call `setMovementMethod()` as described in @spatulamania's answer.

Answer (score 0):

> No need to give HTML commands to link up the URL's and Numbers if you
>   follow bellow way of representation of string.

**-->assume you have string in strings.xml folder**

```
    <string name="string_name">Welcome to www.google.com .It is the worlds best online search engine.</string>
```

**--> Now in you xml file TextView widget add the following attribute.**

```
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="15dp"
           android:autoLink="all"
           android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
           android:text="@string/string_name"
           android:id="@+id/id_string_name_textView" />
```

The magic happens now..just run the code and see the changes which are automatically allow the link up the URL's and numbers.

if you want to give descriptive data to link up string use the following statement programmatically to the TextView

```
string_name_textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```