# Why link does not work in the text view?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I have the link in my TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/app_description" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The link is a part of the resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="app_description">Some text with the <a href="http://www.example.com">link</a>.</string>
</resources>
```

Somehow the link doesn't work. What could be a reason?
It is displayed like a link. But click doesn't open the browser.

Class code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Did you tried with android:clickable="true" ?

Comment: See if [How do I make links in a TextView clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable) or [Links in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790746/links-in-textview) questions helps.

Comment: Try this: android:autoLink="web"

Comment: @Hardy, thanks, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use http link this way:

```
   mLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
      if (mLink != null) {
        mLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
     }
```

In XML:

```
android:autoLink="all"
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer together with http://stackoverflow.com/a/6892799/604388 helped.

Comment: With android:autoLink="all" or android:autoLink="web" in the xml, it doesn't work!

Comment: Remove android:autoLink="all" in the XML works.

Answer (score 9):

Important, if you are using:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=https://www.google.com/>Click</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=https://www.google.com/>Click</a>"));
}
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**Do not set** `android:autoLink="all"` or `android:autoLink="web"` in the xml,  because **with that it doesn't work!**

Answer (score 1):

TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId );

```
    yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    Spannable spans = (Spannable) yourTextView.getText();

    ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.yourTextViewId :
                Intent localIntent = new Intent();
                localIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                localIntent.setData(Uri.parse("YOUR LINK"));
                startActivity(localIntent);
                break;
            }

        }
    };
    spans.setSpan(clickSpan, 0, spans.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Following code is working for me.

```
String html2 = "<br><br>Fire - <b><a href=http://www.google.com>google</a> </b></br></br>";
        text.append(Html.fromHtml(html2));
        text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```