# Phone numbers like links in TextView

Tags: java, android

In `TextView` I need to do reference numbers. Phone numbers in the format `+xxx xx xxxxxxx` only. For this I use the property `android:autoLink="phone"`. But not all phone numbers are recognized correctly - some are broken down into two links, although all are in the same format.

Tell me, how do I can fix this?

Comment: did you try `Linkify` ?

Comment: Could you provide **some** phone numbers that are not recognized, please?

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18571554/1405983

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
  android:linksClickable="true"
  android:autoLink="phone"
```