# Clickable URL in Android-Studio TextView does not work

Tags: android-studio, textview

My Link looks like a link (itś color is blue) but when I click, nothing happens. Do you have any ideas? I use an external string where i want to put in the clickable URL.
Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/anthrazit">





    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textinfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/lightwhite"
            android:text="@string/info"
            android:linksClickable="true"/>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My java:

```
    public class info extends MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
    
    
    
            final TextView infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textinfo);
            infoTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode ==
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            intent = new Intent(info.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    }
```

And my string. I found the code online, but in my Version it does not work :-( :

```
<string name="info">
       

        <i><a href="some site">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</a></i>


    </string>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why link does not work in the text view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571191/why-link-does-not-work-in-the-text-view)

Comment: Yes, it works now! I added  android:autoLink="web" in my textview. Thank you!